# RichTextBox Hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox

I have a WPF **richtextbox** that contains text and hyperlinks. I want to change the font size for the selected hyperlink when i press a button. The problem that i have is that i am not able to get the selected hyperlink from the richtextbox selection.

Best Regards

Marian

PS. I've uploaded a demo here: http://cid-6d5e36974c8e12a8.office.live.com/self.aspx/RTB%20Hyperlink/RTBDemo.zip

PS2. Adding hyperlink to rtb at caret position:

```
Run hyper = new Run("SampleLink");
Hyperlink hp = new Hyperlink(hyper);
hp.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(hp_Click);
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.FontSize = 10;
tb.Inlines.Add(hp);
using (rtb.DeclareChangeBlock())
{
    TextPointer tp = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    InlineUIContainer inlineUIContainer = new InlineUIContainer(tb, tp);
    rtb.CaretPosition = inlineUIContainer.ElementEnd;
}
rtb.IsDocumentEnabled = true;
```

PS3. Setting font:

```
TextRange text = new TextRange(rtb.Selection.Start, rtb.Selection.End);
text.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 14.00);
```

Solved: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/23fcf1b7-8708-40ca-b3b0-658a96a795eb/#b2f32824-fab6-45cc-8c81-7c26986b12bf

Comment: Pasting the relevant code in your question, instead of a link to demo code that must be downloaded, will improve the chances that you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/23fcf1b7-8708-40ca-b3b0-658a96a795eb/#b2f32824-fab6-45cc-8c81-7c26986b12bf

Comment: It's helpful to actually post the corrected code as an answer so that others having the same or similar issue have a better example of how to correct their own issues...